# Not able to pull docker image

Tags: docker

Not able to pull docker image, when run below:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

error response :

> docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unable to connect to 34.237.163.104:443. Do you need an HTTP proxy?.
> See 'docker run --help'.

- Docker Desktop Version=4.9.0 (80466)
- Windows Version: Window 10 Enterprise version 1809 OS build 17763.1098
- Running inside a standalone machine

No Proxy Settings set as access to internet is without any proxy.

Comment: The IP address doesn't seem to be pinged...

Comment: @KubePony don't rely on `ping` for network diagnostics. That fact that something doesn't respond to `ping` doesn't say anything about the availability of services.

Comment: This looks strictly like a network infrastructure problem -- i.e., something specific to your environment for which we won't be able to provide much help. Either there is something in your connectivity that blocks access to that particular address, or you are getting a DNS response containing an invalid address. If you run the command multiple times, does it always fail the same way? Docker hub has multiple ip addresses, so I would expect it to see it trying a different address each time.

Comment: Yes if I try multiple  times it fails in same way and each time ip address mentioned is different

Comment: Is there any way I can see docker logs to see why it is failing to diagnosis it properly. Currently I am at dead end

Comment: Have you tried with other images available from docker-hub ?

Comment: yes  I tried but same response